# TypeScript export class based on config

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, typeof

Ok, firstly TypeScript is pretty new to me, I am a long term C#ist, but loving what I can quickly hack up in Node/TypeScript - I have a syntax problem (I think), I have an interface which is implemented by 2 concrete classes, and a 3rd module which exports one of these concrete classes based on config, ie

**fruit.ts**

```
export interface Fruit {
  eat();
}
```

**apple.ts**

```
export class Apple implements Fruit {
  eat() { console.log('Eat apple'); }
}
```

**banana.ts**

```
export class Banana implements Fruit {
  eat() { console.log('Eat banana'); }
}
```

**breakfast.ts**

```
import { Fruit } from 'fruit';
import { Apple } from 'apple';
import { Banana } from 'banana;

const BreakfastType: typeof Fruit = config.appleForBreakfast ? Apple : Banana;   <-- Error

export { BreakfastType }
```

This looks like it should work for me, Apple and Banana are "types of fruit" so declaring BreakfastType as "typeof Fruit" I would think makes sense, but TypeScript is complaining about

*Fruit only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here*

This is obviously a contrived example, but matches exactly what I am trying to do, I want other code to

```
import { BreakfastType } from 'breakfast';
let breakfastFood = new BreakfastType();    <-- create Apple or Banana based on config
```

Any suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So, there're a few problems here, the first one is that you *can't* use `typeof` for typescript types, but you *can* use it only for js variables, classes, object and all other non typescript stuff. So the next line should *not* have `typeof Fruit`:

```
const BreakfastType: typeof Fruit = config.appleForBreakfast ? Apple : Banana;
```

Instead it needs to be like that:

```
const BreakfastType: Fruit = config.appleForBreakfast ? Apple : Banana;
```

But there's another problem arises, it still complaining about types: `Property 'eat' is missing in type 'typeof Apple' but required in type 'Fruit'`. And after doing some research, I've found that if you specify `BreakfastType` in the way above, typescript sees it in this way:

It treats `BreakfastType` as a variable of a type `Fruit`, but we try to assign `Apple` or `Banana` to it. But they are *classes*, not an *instance* of these classes. So, as a solution you can explicitly state that `BreakfastType` is a class, not an instance with `new () => Fruit`

```
const BreakfastType: (new () => Fruit) = config.appleForBreakfast ? Apple : Banana
const MyBreakfast = new BreakfastType() // MyBreakfast will have Fruit type now
```

Hope it helps ^_^

Comment: thanks for that - the "new() => Fruit" syntax is new to me, I had initially come to a different solution which was to export a function which returned a new instance of Fruit based on the config - but yours is what I was really after - many thanks :)